# Why wouldn't it be good to store lots of data in eos logs instead of smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, nodeos, block-producer

'm curious where to save big data. I don't want to save it in my private db and not in ipfs. I want it to be visible on blockchain. So It's visible on blockchain etherscan If I'd go to store data in logs.

Question 1) Is it the best solution to store huge data in logs ? I don't want somewhere else. it must be visible on blockchain

Question 2) Why would I choose eos smart contract to ethereum's smart contract? I know it's free. but still it has stake, and what if after some time i unstaked it and eos's value went to 0.5$ when I bought it for 5$ each. Then I still lost and it was not free at all

Question 3) do eos logs work the way ethereum's logs work? can I filter them while getting them? or search some kind of data in logs? in ethereum it's easy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Answers for all the questions are numbered accordingly.

1. Yes, if possible in tree structure, so that the search is very easy.
   Infact, all the decentralized cloud are transparent as well.
2. Ethereum vs EOS

   - Ethereum has free account creation, but EOS has some cost which mainly depends on RAM price.
   - gas price during each transaction. But EOS has feeless transactions.
   - Ethereum currently can't segregate actions of different contracts, which EOS very easily does. Moreover, there are 2 types of actions on EOS - inline (validated on network at that time) and deferred (set a time on its execution).
   - Currently, Ethereum can't process dApps at the required speed, but on EOS there are already few games launched - dice, eos knights, etc. which are running very smoothly without delay.

     So, regarding the price, the feeless transaction, present in EOS is due to the token stake. So, basically one risks the inflation/deflation of token price value in the market. Therefore, a person might make a profit or loss eventually after unstaking.
3. Although EOS architecture is completely different than Ethereum. But, definitely you can run the search for any kind of data.

Comment: Also the possibillity to update your smart contracts code is a major benefit for EOS.

Comment: Yes!! True. Will add in the ans.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Ethereum currently can't segregate actions of different contracts" please? What does it mean to segregate actions of different contracts?

Comment: @ByteDisciple It's because of "Data persistence" feature in EOS Smart contracts.
Some data can be stored in EOS contract's RAM. Try an Example and you will understand what I meant by my statement about Ethereum.

Check here - [Data persistence from EOS Developer documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/data-persistence)

Comment: Is it correct to say that eos contract data is saved within the scope of the contract, whereas all ethereum contract data is global?

Comment: I am not updatef with ethereum's current version of SC.